# Convolution operator is compact over $L^2[0,2\pi]$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $h:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ a $2\pi$-periodic and locally integrable. Then we define the operator \begin{eqnarray}T_h: L^2[0,2\pi]\longrightarrow L^2[0,2\pi] \\ T_hf=f*h
\end{eqnarray}
I've already prove that is well-defined, bouded and linear. But I can't prove that 
it is also a compact operator. I'm stuck at this point. I've tried to simplify the problem and considered h an indicator function. Also I took a bounded sequence in $L^2[0,2\pi]$ and tried to prove that its image under $T_h$ has a convergent subsequence.

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two hints: (i) Trigonometric polynomials are dense in $L^1(\mathbb T)$. (ii) If each $T_n$ has finite rank and $||T_n-T||\to0$ then $T$ is compact.